# SharePoint 2010 Data View Joined Subview Filter Empty Rows

Tags: filter, dataview

I've got two lists.  I've created a dataview webpart and have created a joined subview.  The data that is presented is correct.  In the below example, there would be a match for all items with the exception of Item 3. It would display like the following:

Item 1     United States
Item 2     Canada
Item 3     No Item Exists ...
Item 4     Mexico

My current list has more than 800 items.  What I would like to do is create a filter that only would show me:

Item 3        No Item Exists ......

I'm able to do conditional formatting to change the "No Item Exists...." a different color but I would really like to only display a record where there is no match.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually tried it but you may be able to this with a custom XSLT template to display when no items are found.